# Plotting Bessel Functions

Tags: plotting

As the subject title to the post suggests, I am trying to plot a Bessel function on Mathematica. The plot I am trying to create for can be seen below.

$\frac{d(J_m (x))}{dx}$ for $m=0,1,2,3,4$ and $0 \leq x \leq10$

To plot for the above Bessel function, please refer to the below code I wrote as my attempt at plotting the Bessel function.

`f[x_]:=BesselJ[m,x],{m,1,4}`

`Plot[f'[x],{x,0,10}]`

However, Mathematica just gives me syntax error protesting that my BesselJ function needs more input. The error aside, though, I am also having a bit of trouble finding ways to plot the 5 Bessel function lines (for the different $m$'s).

Thank you for reading through the post and any help toward resolving my question would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @Bill , thank you for the help!

As a bit something extra, I wanted to label my given plot so I can immediately identify which line corresponds to which value for $m$. 

I did try writing the code ```Plot[f'[x],{x,0,10},PlotLabels->{"m=0","m=1","m=2","m=3","m=4"}] ```, but that only labeled $m=0$ while the other lines did not get labeled at all.

I did also try ```Plot[f'[x],{x,0,10},PlotLabels->Placed[Automatic, Above]]```, but that did not work either.

If possible, do you mind suggesting a good piece of code to help label all my Bessel function lines to its corresponding $m$ value?

Comment: `Clear[f];
f[x_] = Table[BesselJ[m, x], {m, 0, 4}];
Plot[f'[x] // Evaluate, {x, 0, 10}, 
 PlotLabels -> {"m=0", "m=1", "m=2", "m=3", "m=4"}]`